# ConTeXt: Disable Hyphenation, Enable Indentation, and Enable Sorting for Bibliography Entries (Items in List of Publications)

Tags: bibliographies, indentation, context, hyphenation, sorting

### Enable Indentation

---

I've tried:

```
\setuplist
[pubs][
  before={\indentation},
]
```

and also:

```
\setuppublications[
  indentnext={yes},
  indenting={yes},
]
```

Unfortunately, no effect. I would like both the number and the first line of a bibliography entry to be indented for every entry like this:

```
    1 ...
...
...
    2 ...
...
    3 ...
...
```

### Disable Hyphenation

---

Again, doesn't work:

```
\setuppublications[
  before={
    \setupalign
    [nothyphenated, flushleft]
  },
]
```

### Enable Sorting

---

I have a requirement that bibliography entries should be sorted in the order in which they are cited across the document. How to achieve that?

```
\setuppublications[
  sorttype={cite},
]
```

has nothing to do with it, but the name of the option is quite misleading then. What does it actually do?